# Calling multiple ant targets from ant

Tags: java, ant, build

From my main build file, I would like to call the same target in multiple other build files. My current solution is to call them separately, like so:

```
<ant antfile="${lib_src_dir}/mylib1/build.xml" target="build" inheritAll="false"/>
<ant antfile="${lib_src_dir}/mylib2/build.xml" target="build" inheritAll="false"/>
```

I would like my build file to just call the build target on the build files in all of the subdirectories of `${lib_src_dir}`. I know I could use the [`foreach`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) tasks from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), but I'd like to stay away from an external library if possible.

I've tried the following, which didn't work:

```
<ant antfile="${lib_src_dir}/*/build.xml" target="build" inheritAll="false"/>
```

Comment: I just noticed the subant task. That might do what I want. http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with, using the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task:

```
<subant target="clean">
    <fileset dir="${lib_src_dir}" includes="*/build.xml" />
</subant>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task.

Comment: Hah, I just noticed your comment above.